# Accommodation for a large group in Cairns in November 2012

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, australia, group-travel, cairns

I'm organising a largish group (around 10, hopefully) to go to Cairns in November for the total solar eclipse on the 14th.

With a group that size, it'd be nice if we could have a place to ourselves - when I travel I love hostels, but if we could find an apartment or house for a couple of nights which could hold about 10 people, that would be perfect.

Any online sources people can recommend to look for such a place in Australia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used the site specifically for Cairns, but I have found some great places using the Stayz http://www.stayz.com.au/ website.

You can usually find a variety of places (large house, guest accommodation or cabins etc.) to cater for a larger group.

The prices are generally better than a typical hotel or hostel, the people are generally nicer and the range of activities are usually better (many places provide equipment such as kayaks or big screen TV or fishing equipment etc.).

I am not affiliated with this site, just a very pleased customer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this site:

[hostelzoo listings for Cairns](http://hostelzoo.com/oceania/australia/cairns/#0)

Yes I am affiliated with hostelzoo, but I took a group to the Cairns Central YHA and had a really great time.

Have fun no matter where you go.

Comment: Thanks, but while I enjoy hostels, some of the group would certainly prefer an apartment/house.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Like many hostel sites, not only hostels are listed. If you look in the left sidebar you will see there are some options:

Bed Type: Dorms, Privates

Property Type: Hostels, Camping, Apartments, Hotels, Other

6 aparments are listed there, might get you started at least?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yha.com.au/

Used it myself for Cairns.

**Update:**

Youth Hostelling Association of Australia. Low cost accomodation, mostly dorms/shared.

I used it myself as a single traveller but shared a dorm with 3 others. One bathroom in the dorm. Food/catering is extra, not included.

I suggest it as you are a large group so this could suit you if you divide your group into several dorms.

Staff were fine - you can book tours from the main desk.